# Why are strings interpreted wrong in MatLab code with listings

Tags: listings, matlab, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to include MatLab code in my document using the listings package, but it seems like strings are not interpreted correct.

```
fprintf('ABC %s:\n', mystring);
fprintf("ABC %s:\n", mystring);
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     %use english or ngerman
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %German äöü for input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        %German äöü for pdf
\usepackage{textcomp}           %Additional Symbols e.g. degree
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{keyword}{RGB}{0,175,203}      %color
\definecolor{comment}{rgb}{0.06,0.58,0.07} %color
\definecolor{label}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}      %color

\lstset{                                   %Configure code
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{keyword},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{label},
  commentstyle=\color{comment}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    language=MatLab,
    label=lst:broken,
    caption={Broken Syntax Highlighting}
]
fprintf('ABC %s:\n', mystring);
fprintf("ABC %s:\n", mystring);
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result of the MWE]

Is it possible to add `"` to the same list that `'` is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Matlab language definition only defines `'` as string delimiter by default. But you can also make `"` one by adding the following line to the listing's options:

```
morestring=[m]"
```

`m` is a special delimiter type for Matlab code defined as

> [...] a special type for Ada and Matlab and
>   possibly other languages where the string delimiters are also used for other
>   purposes. It is equivalent to `d`, except that a string does not start after a
>   letter, a right parenthesis, a right bracket, or some other characters.

If you don't want that special behavior, use `morestring=[d]"`.

You can also define a new language which is based on Matlab with the new string type added:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{MyMatlab}{
  language=Matlab,
  morestring=[m]"
}
```

Using that new language in your listing gives the desired output:

[image]